# Draw a line between objects in Android

Tags: android, line, draw

Hello I have a layout with x number of buttons created dinamically. What i need to do is draw a line that join the first and the last button. How can i get position of the buttons, and how can i draw the line?
Thanks!

Comment: You can get coordinates from view.getLocationOnScreen()

Comment: how can I reference the first and the last button? by id?

Comment: This post may help you ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781353/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android-between-two-or-more-radiobuttons

Comment: you can use GridLayout instead and have some separator/divider in that..!!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you draw the line:

```
canvas.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y, paint);
```

This is done to the canvas object in the `onDraw` method.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) is more information: