# Custom Draw Line Between Two Views Not Working Properly

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am trying to draw lines between buttons in android. I created one custom class which draw line between buttons inside relative layout(Relative Layout is parent layout).

> Here is my MatchTheColoumnDrawView.java class which accepts context, startView, endView, lineColour, endCircleColour, thickness(in float), direction(LEFT_TO_RIGHT OR RIGHT_TO_LEFT).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Abhishek on 12/21/2016.
 *
 * Changes made as per new design on Date 9 Oct 2017
 *
 */

public class MatchTheColumnDrawView extends View {


    public static final int LEFT_TO_RIGHT = 1, RIGHT_TO_LEFT = 2;

    private Paint mLinePaint, mCirclePaint;

    private View startView, endView;

    private int direction;

    private Canvas canvas;

    private float dashWidth = 15f;

    private float dashGap = 8f;

    float[] intervals = new float[]{dashWidth, dashGap};

    float phase = 0;

    private int LINE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#BEBEBE");

    private int END_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#FF99CC00");

    /**
     *
     * parametrised constructor draws line from
     * @startView
     * to
     * @endView
     * as per
     * @direction
     * and
     * @lineColor
     * and
     * @endCircleColor
     *
     * when
     * @lineColor == null
     * default lineColor is gray
     *
     * when
     * @endCircleColor == null
     * default endCircleColor is green
     * */

    public MatchTheColumnDrawView(Context context,
                                  View startView, View endView,
                                  String lineColor, String endCircleColor,
                                  float thickness, int direction) {

        super(context);

        mLinePaint = new Paint();
        if (lineColor != null) LINE_COLOR = Color.parseColor(lineColor);
        mLinePaint.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
        mLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(thickness);
        mLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        if (endCircleColor != null) END_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.parseColor(endCircleColor);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(END_CIRCLE_COLOR);
        mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(thickness);

        this.startView = startView;
        this.endView = endView;
        this.direction = direction;

        //setBackgroundColor To Transparent
        super.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    public View getStartView() {
        return startView;
    }

    public void setStartView(View startView) {
        this.startView = startView;
    }

    public View getEndView() {
        return endView;
    }

    public void setEndView(View endView) {
        this.endView = endView;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public int getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(int direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        this.canvas = canvas;

        Log.d("Direction", String.valueOf(direction));

        Log.d("Start View Y:", String.valueOf(startView.getY()));
        Log.d("Start View H:", String.valueOf(startView.getHeight()));

        Log.d("End View Y:", String.valueOf(endView.getY()));
        Log.d("End View H:", String.valueOf(endView.getHeight()));

        //By default takes LEFT_TO_RIGHT

        if (direction == RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {

            //For RIGHT TO LEFT
            //Calculating Left X And Mid Of Height Y
            /*
            *                   ______________
            *                  |              |
            * This Point ==>> .|              |
            *                  |              |
            *                  |______________|
            * */

            float startViewLeftX = startView.getX();
            float startViewMidHeightY = startView.getY() + startView.getHeight() / 2;

            //Calculating Right X And Mid Of Height Y
            /*
            *     ______________
            *    |              |
            *    |              |.  <<== This Point
            *    |              |
            *    |______________|
            * */

            float endViewRightX = endView.getX() + endView.getWidth(); //20 is just to remove unwanted padding on Right Side
            float endViewMidHeightY = endView.getY() + endView.getHeight() / 2;

            Path mPath = new Path();

            mPath.moveTo(startViewLeftX, startViewMidHeightY);
            mPath.lineTo(endViewRightX, endViewMidHeightY);

            DashPathEffect dashPathEffect = new DashPathEffect(intervals, phase);

            mLinePaint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mLinePaint);

            //canvas.drawLine(startViewLeftX, startViewMidHeightY, endViewRightX, endViewMidHeightY, mLinePaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(startViewLeftX, startViewMidHeightY, 5, mCirclePaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(endViewRightX, endViewMidHeightY, 5, mCirclePaint);
        } else {

            //FOR LEFT_TO_RIGHT
            //Calculating Right X And Mid Of Height Y
            /*
            *     ______________
            *    |              |
            *    |              |.  <<== This Point
            *    |              |
            *    |______________|
            * */

            float startViewRightX = startView.getX() + startView.getWidth(); //20 is just to remove unwanted padding on Right Side
            float startViewMidHeightY = startView.getY() + startView.getHeight() / 2;

            //Calculating Left X And Mid Of Height Y
            /*
            *                   ______________
            *                  |              |
            * This Point ==>> .|              |
            *                  |              |
            *                  |______________|
            * */

            float endViewLeftX = endView.getX();
            float endViewMidHeightY = endView.getY() + endView.getHeight() / 2;

            Path mPath = new Path();

            mPath.moveTo(startViewRightX, startViewMidHeightY);
            mPath.lineTo(endViewLeftX, endViewMidHeightY);

            DashPathEffect dashPathEffect = new DashPathEffect(intervals, phase);

            mLinePaint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mLinePaint);
            //canvas.drawLine(startViewRightX, startViewMidHeightY, endViewLeftX, endViewMidHeightY, mLinePaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(startViewRightX, startViewMidHeightY, 5, mCirclePaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(endViewLeftX, endViewMidHeightY, 5, mCirclePaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }


}
```

> I wrote one class MatchTheFollowingAttempted which extend Relative layout and it contains logic for drawing buttons and lines between them. Here is MatchTheFollowingAttempted.java class.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Abhishek on 24-10-2017.
 */

public class MatchTheFollowingAttempted extends RelativeLayout {

    private Context mContext;

    int numberOfOneSideButtons = 5;


    public MatchTheFollowingAttempted(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        initialiseView();
    }

    public MatchTheFollowingAttempted(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        initialiseView();
    }

    public MatchTheFollowingAttempted(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContext = context;
        initialiseView();
    }

    public MatchTheFollowingAttempted(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        mContext = context;
        initialiseView();
    }

    public void initialiseView() {

        ArrayList<Button> leftSideButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Button> rightSideButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<MatchTheColumnDrawView> matchTheColumnDrawViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOneSideButtons; i++) {

            Button mButton = new Button(mContext);

            mButton.setId(View.generateViewId());

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            if (i != 0) {

                layoutParams.addRule(BELOW, leftSideButtons.get(i-1).getId());

            }

            layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

            mButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            leftSideButtons.add(mButton);

            addView(mButton);


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOneSideButtons; i++) {

            Button mButton = new Button(mContext);

            mButton.setId(View.generateViewId());

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            layoutParams.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

            if (i != 0) {

                layoutParams.addRule(BELOW, rightSideButtons.get(i-1).getId());

            }

            layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

            mButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            rightSideButtons.add(mButton);

            addView(mButton);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOneSideButtons; i++) {

            MatchTheColumnDrawView matchTheColumnDrawView = new MatchTheColumnDrawView(mContext, leftSideButtons.get(i), rightSideButtons.get(4-i), null, null, 2.0f, MatchTheColumnDrawView.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

            matchTheColumnDrawViewArrayList.add(matchTheColumnDrawView);

            addView(matchTheColumnDrawView);
        }



    }

}
```

> When I directly use MatchTheFollowingAttempted inside LinearLayout(Inside Scrollview) it will shows view properly with buttons and lines between them. As shown in image attached(Image_One). Here is the xml for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <MatchTheFollowingAttempted
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </MatchTheFollowingAttempted>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Image_One]

> But when I add second MatchTheFollowingAttempted in Linear Layout Then Lines will not shown(As in attached image Image_Two). Here is xml with two MatchTheFollowingAttempted in Linear Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <MatchTheFollowingAttempted
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </MatchTheFollowingAttempted>

            <MatchTheFollowingAttempted
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </MatchTheFollowingAttempted>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Image_Two]

> When I run it real its not showing second layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are adding `MatchTheColumnDrawView`s programmatically to `MatchTheFollowingAttempted` without setting `LayoutParams`. There are default values for `LayoutParams`, so with just one instance of  `MatchTheFollowingAttempted` you were simply lucky.

So to fix the problem you have to set `LayoutParams` to the `MatchTheColumnDrawView`s, for example like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOneSideButtons; i++) {

    MatchTheColumnDrawView matchTheColumnDrawView = new MatchTheColumnDrawView(
                       mContext, leftSideButtons.get(i), 
                       rightSideButtons.get(numberOfOneSideButtons - 1 - i),
                       null, null,
                       2.0f, MatchTheColumnDrawView.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(ALIGN_TOP, 
                  leftSideButtons.get(0).getId());
    layoutParams.addRule(ALIGN_BOTTOM, 
                  leftSideButtons.get(numberOfOneSideButtons - 1).getId());
    matchTheColumnDrawView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    matchTheColumnDrawViewArrayList.add(matchTheColumnDrawView);

    addView(matchTheColumnDrawView);
}
```

If your left side and right side `Button`s have very varying heights then you will have to find a better formula but the idea is to request as much space as possible but not the whole screen (else the next custom `View` will not be shown at all), so try to align the `MatchTheColumnDrawView` bottom to the lowest `Button` bottom.

[image: two custom views]

P.S. How did I find out?

Using Android Studio's Layout Inspector on your `View` (BTW thanks for posting the full code!) showed that the "missing"  `View`s actually had a height of 0.

Overriding `onMeasure()` in `MatchTheColumnDrawView` to log the measured width and height confirmed this: `RelativeLayout` does two layout passes: having a height of 0 after the first pass may happen, but after the second pass the `View` should have some height > 0 or it will not be shown.

**EDIT:**

In `MatchTheFollowingAttempted`, you set a padding to each of the Buttons
The green circles will be drawn exactly in the middle of the `View`'s edge if you subtract the padding when calculating the mid height values, e.g.

```
float endViewMidHeightY = endView.getY() + endView.getHeight() / 2 - 10;
```

Because a `Button` has its own padding (it looks smaller than it actually is), the circles still do not overlap the visible `Button` edge. To achieve this, either use your own Button background or (kind of hacky because the padding may change in future Android versions) subtract the padding from the x coordinate (left side) respectively add the padding to the x coordinate (right side) .

The screenshot below shows an example with some custom `View`s and some `Button`s:

[image]

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Abhishek - you're welcome!  It took some time to solve this, and I enjoyed it very much, not least because your detailed question enabled me to run tests instead of just guessing.

Comment: How I can start the selection line from mid point of edges? Any solution?

Comment: @Abhishek - do you mean like the green dots should have the mid points as their center points?

Comment: Green Dot is at center of button height & at button X + width if button is left side button and center of button height & at button X if its right side button. As in image one. When I set layout param green dot start always at bottom of button

Comment: @0X0nosugar is there any possibility to do that kind of design with linear layout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59698156/on-draw-method-is-not-calling-in-my-application?noredirect=1#comment105555193_59698156        Here I posted my code can you pls check if I gave more than 6 buttons unable to draw lines

Comment: @Mounika - I will have the time to look into the problem in about ten hours. In order to minimize downvotes, you could add a link to this answer in your question and explain that you're trying to switch over to LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">

 <Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#313131"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="3dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to add it only through MatchTheFollowingAttempted. Because I want to use draw lines dynamically.

Comment: Then You have to use List Adapter add view based on the scenario you can hide and show the line.