# How to draw a line between two TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, gridview, textview

I have a gridlayout with TextViews. Every textview have some bacground color. I want to draw line betwen TextView "A" and TextView "B". How to do this? I have to use canvas and onDrawMethod(..)?

[image]

Comment: If this contain only two Text and single line then you can make it a Single Custom View .

Comment: No, in grid layout there is a lot text Views

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46911682/5015207) will help you

Answer (score 0):

create a diagonal shaped xml and add in your drawable. below is code to create diagonal shape, then use imageView to set drawable.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
  <rotate
   android:fromDegrees="160"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:toDegrees="0">
    <shape
     android:shape="line"
     android:top="1dip">
    <stroke
       android:width="3dp"
       android:color="#FF0000"/>
        </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Hope it helps!