# How to Draw a animated line on an image in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-shapedrawable

**Screenshot of my app**

[image]

What i want is draw a line between 2 points on an image(please See image Attached here) When user click Ok button and this line must be not directly drawned it takes total time of 10 sec to draw(some what like google maps)
please let me know how this line can be drawn.

Thanks in advance.Any help is appreciated

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android

Comment: might be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781353/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android-between-two-or-more-radiobuttons

Comment: @JayPatel actually i know how this line can be drawn, but i want to draw this line slowly in a period of 40 sec. Please help me