# Line between two textViews is not drawing in customView

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have two column of textView containing some text.
When you click in one text then click in another from other column it should draw a line between them.
I have put a relative layout between the two textView columns and adding a customised view to it.
I debugged and found that its calling the onDraw to draw line but i can not see any lines
Here is my code for that.

```
public class DrawLineView extends View {


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    View startView;
    View endView;

    public DrawLineView(Context context, View startView, View endView) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.startView = startView;
        this.endView = endView;
        invalidate();
    }

    public DrawLineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    //    public void drawLineNow() {
//
//        invalidate();
//    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawLine(startView.getX() + 25, startView.getY() + 50, endView.getX() + 25, endView.getY(), paint);
    }


}
```

This is called in something like this.

```
selectedTextFromColumn2 = texviewC2T4;
selectedTag2 = list2.get(3).getTag();
if (selectedTag1 == selectedTag2) {
    drawLineView = new DrawLineView(MatchingContentScreen.this,selectedTextFromColumn1, selectedTextFromColumn2);
    relativeLayout.addView(drawLineView);
    drawLineView.invalidate();

}
```

I am new to canvas .So i am confused what i am doing wrong or missing.

the line coming as a vertical line
[image: line coming as a vertical line]

I saw this drawing solution from another post.

[How to draw a line in android between two or more RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781353/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android-between-two-or-more-radiobuttons)

Can anyone please help me ?

I want it something like this

[image: expected]

I can draw line like this if canvas is on top of these textviews
using

```
 canvas.drawLine(startX , startY , stopX , stopY, paint);
```

but i can not validate the text or read the textview to match.

Comment: what's your expected? can you provide an scratch of it?

Comment: I suggest you to use RecyclerView and draw this lines via ItemDecoration.